# Differing definitions of a connection on a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-products, connections

My lecture notes define a connection on a vector bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow{M}$ to be an $\mathbb{R}$-linear map:
\begin{equation}
\nabla:\Gamma(E)\rightarrow\Gamma(T^*M\otimes{E})
\end{equation}

satisfying the Leibniz rule $\nabla(fs)=\mathrm{d}f\otimes{s}+f\nabla{s}$ for all $f\in{C^{\infty}(M)}$, $s\in\Gamma(E)$.

Then given a vector field $X$ on $M$, the covariant derivative along $X$ is the map
\begin{equation}
\nabla_X:\Gamma(E)\rightarrow\Gamma(E)
\end{equation} 
such that for $s\in\Gamma(E)$, $\nabla_Xs=\mathrm{Tr}(X\otimes\nabla{s})$, that is, the contraction of the first two components of $X\otimes\nabla{s}\in{TM}\otimes{T^*M}\otimes{E}$ (I think it's okay to omit the $\Gamma$'s here for simplicity, and that this isn't a mistake?)

However, I'm trying to reconcile this definition with what I'm finding in almost every other source, which is as follows: with the same set up as above, a connection is a map 
\begin{equation}
\nabla:\Gamma(TM)\times\Gamma(E)\rightarrow\Gamma(E)
\end{equation}

satisfying $C^\infty$-linearity in the first component, $\mathbb{R}$-linearity in the second component, and the product rule $\nabla_X(fs)=f\nabla_X{s}+(Xf)s$ for all $f\in{C^\infty(M)}$. In this case, the image $\nabla_Xs$ of $(X,s)$ under $\nabla$ is *defined* to be the covariant derivative of $s$ in the direction $X$. This definition seems considerably easier to work with, so I would like to make the link between them.

I imagine it might have something to do with the identification between $\mathrm{Hom}(TM,E)$ and $T^*M\otimes{E}$, but I haven't got further than that.

Comment: Yes, precisely. $\text{Hom}(V,W) \cong V^*\otimes W$.

Comment: How exactly can I incorporate this, though?

Comment: Having a $1$-form $\omega\in\Gamma(T^*M)$ is the same thing as giving a map $\Gamma(TM)\to\Bbb R$ (with suitable properties). Given a vector field $X\in\Gamma(TM)$, we get a smooth function by taking $\omega(X)$, the contraction $\omega\otimes X\to \omega(X)$. On the other hand, given a map $\psi\colon\Gamma(TM)\to\Bbb R$, we define $\omega\in\Gamma(T^*M)$ by $\omega(p)(v) = \psi(X)(p)$ where $X$ is any vector field with value $v$ at $p$. The "suitable properties" tell us this is well-defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we partially apply your second definition to a section $s \in \Gamma(E)$, we get a $C^\infty(M)$-linear map $\nabla s : \Gamma(TM) \to \Gamma(E)$. You should know the fact that $C^\infty(M)$-linear maps between sheaves of sections are always derived from bundle homomorphisms ("$C^\infty$-linear maps are tensors"); i.e. $$\operatorname{Hom}_{C^\infty(M)}(\Gamma(TM), \Gamma(E)) = \Gamma(\operatorname{Hom}_\mathbb R(TM,E)).$$ Thus $\nabla s$ is in fact a section of $\operatorname{Hom} (TM,E) = T^* M \otimes E$ as desired, and the assignment $s \mapsto \nabla s$ satisfies the Leibniz rule in both definitions.

Comment: Thanks - could you please explain in more detail what you mean by the sheaves part? I don't think I've encountered this.

Comment: @jl2: I'm talking about an easy generalization of what many people call the "Tensor Characterization Lemma". Don't worry about the word "sheaf" if that's throwing you off.  Any section $\xi \in \Gamma({\rm Hom}(E,F))$ induces a $C^\infty(M)$-linear map $\bar\xi : \Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(F)$ defined by $\bar\xi (\alpha)(p) = \xi(\alpha(p))$. The lemma states that this is reversible; i.e. for any $C^\infty$-linear $\Xi :\Gamma(E) \to \Gamma(F)$, there is a $\xi$ such that $\bar \xi = \Xi$. I don't know a good reference for this general version, but most DG texts should prove it for tensors.

Comment: @jl2: leave it to Lee. Introduction to Smooth Manifolds Lemma 10.29 (Bundle Homomorphism Characterization Lemma) is exactly what you want. It's readable at https://books.google.com.au/books?id=xygVcKGPsNwC&pg=PA262 if that link works for you.

Comment: Or, instead of John Lee suggested above, look at Jeffrey Lee's Manifolds and Differential Geometry, Prop. 6.55. That is exactly equality as stated in the answer.